# Setting Oracle XA Client in Tomcat

Tags: oracle, tomcat, xa

How can i setup Oracle XA client in tomcat 6.0 context.xml ?

I tried

```
<Resource name="jdbc/notification" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
     factory="org.objectweb.jotm.datasource.DataSourceFactory"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" removeAbandoned="true" 
            username="NOTIFICATION" password="password" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource"
                        defaultAutoCommit="false" jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalized" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" poolPreparedStatements="true" />
```

But it's throw

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error opening session.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: SQLException in StandardPoolDataSource:getConnection exception: java.sql.SQLException: SQLException in StandardPoolDataSource:getConnection no connection available java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource : oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: SQLException in StandardPoolDataSource:getConnection exception: java.sql.SQLException: SQLException in StandardPoolDataSource:getConnection no connection available java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource : oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
```

Please give me an example how to setup oracle XA client in tomcat 6.

Thanks!!